# Unable to mount Volume Group

Tags: centos, mount, partition, hard-disk, lvm

2 drives connected externally to a new server both are merged using LVM as one drive.

```
vgscan
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "vol_grp1" using metadata type lvm2
Found volume group "vg1" using metadata type lvm2  

 pvscan
PV /dev/sde1   VG vol_grp1   lvm2 [465.76 GiB / 0    free]
PV /dev/sdd1   VG vol_grp1   lvm2 [200.00 GiB / 192.00 MiB free]
PV /dev/sdb1   VG vg1        lvm2 [465.75 GiB / 0    free]
PV /dev/sdc1   VG vg1        lvm2 [465.75 GiB / 0    free]
Total: 4 [1.56 TiB] / in use: 4 [1.56 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

The external drives are /dev/sdd and /dev/sde merged in LVM as /dev/vol_grp1/logical_vol1

I'm trying to mount the volume group but it's not working

```
mount /dev/vol_grp1/logical_vol1 /mnt/usb
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You don't have a valid filesystem there. What makes you think you have one? How did you assemble the volumes after the troubles in your previous questions?

Comment: @Gilles these drives are usb attached since they were on the old server and now i'm migrating the data to the new server I restored the VG from the backup folder and I'm seeing the drive but can't mount them

Comment: **HOW** did you restore the VG? Did you take both disks from the backup? How did you make the backup?

Comment: @Gilles the backup was automatic I think I found the files there and yes I restored both from the backup

Comment: @Gilles trying  mount -l /dev/sdf1 /mnt/usb it gives mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdf1, dmesg | tail sd 20:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 20:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdf: sdf1 sdf2
sd 20:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 20:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk

Answer (score 1):

You still need to format the logical volume with some kind of filesystem. LVM just gets you to the point where you have one resizable volume instead of two fixed size volumes.

Example:

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/vol_grp1/logical_vol1
```

After that, try your `mount` command again.

Comment: thanks for your advise but I can't format this disks they have data and mkfs.ext4 will wipe all the data there. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Um if you've _just_ created these logical volumes then there isn't any data on them. otherwise you may need to specify the filesystem on your `mount` command with the `-t` option.

Comment: @bractchley thanks for the advise I tried all possible filesystem none worked ext3,4,vfat none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a disaster when you want to change something
on lvm you must first do a full backup of volume
with bacula,dd,tar,cpio,amanda,whatever you want.
Then recreate the VG and lvm on new server and restore
from backup 
for example

```
OLD SERVER
VG VG01 1 lvm / #simple case..
NEW SERVER
VG VG02 1 lvm / #simple case..
```

recreate the VG02 on new server with new disk
and put the backup here.
You can do something good also using rsync
rsync all data of VG01 lvms,on new VG02 lvms
in real time,without losing data and time.
The only possible solution is this i think
Did you have a backup?
Can you restore the old vg on the other server?

Comment: I did a backup but unfortunately 2 of the most important accounts are not there. I have a backup in the /etc/lvm/backup for VG and this is what I do. Advise me how to use rsync to sync all data from a partition to directory on remote server.

Comment: simple,if the partition is /usr do `rsyn -avP -e /usr/ remote:/backup/usr` note the use of / at the end of usr and -e (encryption,need ssh)